# place horizontal line (hr) after image (float: left) which has some collapsible text next to it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress page. on the top there is an image with some text collapsible text next to it. after the text, there is an `<hr>`. However, I would like the `<hr>` to be after the image.

how can I achieve this? I already played around with the html in the editor of wordpress, but it gives me a headache.. also the fact, that wordpress seems to add `<p>` tags more or less arbitrarily, doesn't help...

The desired outcome should be like this:

[image]

edit: link added

edit2: added screenshot of desired outcome

Comment: Can you show us what is the desired outcome? With no code and no illustration it is difficult to imagine what you're asking for. And avoid linking to external sites—learn how to create a **[minimal, concrete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** using code snippets.

Comment: sorry. please remove downvote. i now added link + desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hr` tag flows just like text. That means that the image which floats to the left also affects the `hr`.

If you want the `hr` to not be affected by the float, then make it clear the float by adding a `clear: left` style to the `hr`:

```
hr {
    clear: left;
}
```